# How to add an array of records to row from active-record model in a CSV export file in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

I am trying to add records to a row from an active-record model.

The CSV row is:

csv << [ "Question_name", "Question_description" ]

I am having an answer model which contain name attribute. I want to take all the anwer.name from Answer model and append it to the CSV row. so that the CSV row becomes:

csv << [ "Question_name", "Question_description", "ans1", "ans2", "ans3" ]

I tried to fix the issue and got the following code:

```
answers = Answer.all
answers.each {|a| ab << a.name }
data = ab.inject(" ") { |x,n| x << "#{n} " }
data.gsub!(/\s/,',')
csv << [ "Question_name", "Question_description", "#{data}" ]
```

But all the answer.name records were appended in one cell. Please help me to add the answer.name records in different columns

Comment: The question_id field is present in Answer model. The association is like Question has many answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking to acheive this?

```
answers = Answer.all
row = ["Question_name", "Question_description"] + answers.map(&:name)
csv << row
```

Comment: Sure thing! `answers.map(&:name)` is just a short hand for `answers.map { |a| a.name }` and is actually faster than the longhand version!